# Gitonomy cannot access my remote repository

Tags: php, git

I am testing out the Gitonomy Library within PHP and something I just cannot put my finger on. I have created a small application found [here](https://github.com/Luyanda86/gitonomy-test) with a class that uses the Repository class from the library to list available branches on GITHUB Remote REposictory. Below is the class:

```
   namespace LuSoft\Library{

   use Gitonomy\Git\Repository as RemoteRepositroy;

   class Repository
   {
     public function getBranches($repository)
     {
        if(!is_string($repository)){
           throw new Exception("Reposotory must be in a form of a string.");
         }

         $rr = new RemoteRepositroy($repository);

         $branches = [];
         foreach($rr->getReferences()->getBranches() as $branch){
           $branches[] = $branch->getName();
          }

        $rr->run('fetch', array('--all'));

        return $branches;
     }
   }
 }
```

I have followed the example from [here](http://gitonomy.com/doc/gitlib/master/). Below is how I call this class in my index.php page.

```
  require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

  use LuSoft\Library\Repository;

  $repository = new Repository();

  try{

     var_dump($repository->getBranches(__DIR__));
  }catch(\Exception $e){
    echo "Exception :" . $e->getMessage();
  }
```

Below is the error that I get:

> Exception :Error while getting list of references: '"git"' is not
>   recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or
>   batch file.

I am using the application I am testing with to get the branches and if things went on correctly I am suppose to be seeing master.

Can someone please explain to me how does the library really work in simplest form?

NB: My index.php is on the same folder level of the application where git has been initialized.

Comment: Have you set the env PATH for git?

Comment: Yes because I am using the console to test this out e.g $php index.php within my root directory. I hope thats what you meant.